# Did the Faithful leave Númenor unnoticed?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Evil King's men tried to sail west from Númenor to war against the Valar. Meanwhile on the home front, Elendil, Isildur and Anárion are preparing to evacuate. Did they all (the faithful people) escape to the harbors unseen by the King's men, or did they have fight their way to the Nine ships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, but we don't really know. From *Akallabêth* (emphasis mine):

> But whether or no it were that Amandil came indeed to Valinor and Manwë hearkened to his prayer, by grace of the Valar Elendil and his sons and their people were spared from the ruin of that day. For **Elendil had remained in Romenna, refusing the summons of the King when he set forth to war; and avoiding the soldiers of Sauron that came to seize him and drag him to the fires of the Temple, he went aboard his ship and stood off from the shore**, waiting on the time. There he was protected by the land from the great draught of the sea that drew all towards the abyss, and afterwards he was sheltered from the first fury of the storm. But when the devouring wave rolled over the land and Númenor toppled to its fall, then he would have been overwhelmed and would have deemed it the lesser grief to perish, for no wrench of death could be more bitter than the loss and agony of that day; but the great wind took him, wilder than any wind that Men had known, roaring from the west, and it swept his ships far away; and it rent their sails and snapped their masts, hunting the unhappy men like straws upon the water.
>
> Nine ships there were: four for Elendil, and for Isildur three, and for Anárion two; and they fled before the black gale out of the twilight of doom into the darkness of the world.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* VI *Akallabêth*</sub></sup>

That Elendil is described as "avoiding" the soldiers, rather than "fighting" or "dispatching" them suggests to me that he, at least, didn't have to fight his way to his ship.

For the rest of the ships, and the rest of the men *on* those ships, we don't know; since we know that Sauron had soldiers on the island, it's certainly *possible*, but it's not recorded. We do know that the wives and children were placed on their ships ahead of time:

> Elendil did all that his father had bidden, and his ships lay off the east coast of the land; and the Faithful put aboard their wives and their children, and their heirlooms, and great store of goods.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* VI *Akallabêth*</sub></sup>

But that's all the information we have.

Comment: Many of the faithful left long before the cataclysm. They moved quietly to Middle-earth to avoid persecution.